# Apache change CGI interpreter on Windows

Tags: apache, jscript

I'm trying to run my jscript files and return result to client using CGI. But I can't to set first line og mys cript like #!/usr/bin/cscript.exe because jscript not support comments started by # and get error.

**Question:** How can I set path to my CGI interpreter without !#/usr/bin/cscript.exe in the first line of my script?

Answer (score 1):

From my rather dated httpd.conf:

```
# However, Apache on Windows allows either the Unix behavior above, or can
# use the Registry to match files by extention.  The command to execute 
# a file of this type is retrieved from the registry by the same method as 
# the Windows Explorer would use to handle double-clicking on a file.
# These script actions can be configured from the Windows Explorer View menu, 
# 'Folder Options', and reviewing the 'File Types' tab.  Clicking the Edit
# button allows you to modify the Actions, of which Apache 1.3 attempts to
# perform the 'Open' Action, and failing that it will try the shebang line.
# This behavior is subject to change in Apache release 2.0.
#
# Each mechanism has it's own specific security weaknesses, from the means
# to run a program you didn't intend the website owner to invoke, and the
# best method is a matter of great debate.
#
# To enable the this Windows specific behavior (and therefore -disable- the
# equivilant Unix behavior), uncomment the following directive:
#
#ScriptInterpreterSource registry
```

So I enabled the ScriptInterpreterSource feature, checked:

```
ftype JSFile
JSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe "%1" %*
```

and used `c:\programme\xampp\cgi-bin\jscgi.js` containing:

```
WScript.Echo("Content-Type: text/html\n");
WScript.Echo("OK:", WScript.ScriptFullName, new Date());
```

successfully. I did not touch other settings like AddHandler, directory, or
ScriptAlias, and I just tested phpinfo.php and printenv.pl to see if this
change wrecked my installation blatantly - no.

You should be much more prudent.

**Update wrt comment:**

According to the 2.4 docs (search for "ScriptInterpreterSource") the directive is still valid. Are you sure the **apache** user account associates .js files with cscript.exe?

Comment: Which version of Apache do you use? I'm trying same settings on Apache/2.4.4 but it's not work